# Android Instant app not working in my Beta Pre Release testing through the app link

Tags: android, applinks, android-instant-apps

I have my Instant App on Beta pre release but I am not able launch the Instant App through the app link. Instead it is taking me to the web browser. Any help?

Answer (score 3):

I keep having the same issue myself. My solution has been to go to your Instant Apps settings and toggle Instant Apps off and back on again.

You should be able to get there via Settings -> Google -> Instant Apps

Answer (score 2):

You can not see the button because your android instant app is on pre-release track. "**Try Now**" ***button is only shown for instant apps that are published to production.***

Publish your Instant app to production first, then your user will see "Try Now" button in the play store listing.

Comment: is there any way to check my application in pre-release @Pragati

Comment: sure please check bot.touchkin

Answer (score 1):

Similar problem as [pre-release instant app cannot be launched through dynamic link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45241462/pre-release-instant-app-cannot-be-launched-through-dynamic-link/)

If you already tested with alpha or local, please check your distribution area as listed in that question.

Answer (score 0):

This post is old, but still comes on the researches. I did post on Alpha for testing and after one day the button "Try now" was available. Seems that there is a day to Google index some stuff for the InstantApp.