# Instant app pre-release not showing try now button in playstore

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I uploaded instant build in pre-release and added testers with emails but i m not getting **Try Now**  button in play store.

Please don't mark as duplicate, did clear data and re-enable instant apps bit still and not able to access.

I tried these   [re-enable instant apps in settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45492705/android-instant-app-not-working-in-my-beta-pre-release-testing-through-the-app-l)  and [checked distribution countries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45241462/pre-release-instant-app-cannot-be-launched-through-dynamic-link)

Comment: I set the minimum version sdk version  21 for instant application.