# how can I access an Instant app which I have put in pre-release?

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I have created an Instant App and I have uploaded it on Play store in Pre-release mode. But I am not able to test from there. Please someone guide me as soon as possible as I am stuck here.

Comment: Please can you check url https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7381861 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45241462/pre-release-instant-app-cannot-be-launched-through-dynamic-link?noredirect=1&lq=1 for understanding about Instant app pre-release.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add testers to the pre-released app. [image: Check out this screenshot]

Add your tester's email to the list by clicking dropdown on the right where it says `closed test using testers list`. Once you add the testers to the list you are all set.