# InstantApp not loading

Tags: android, deep-linking, android-instant-apps

I have a variation of circumstances but the same basic problem as [SO#45241462](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45241462/pre-release-instant-app-cannot-be-launched-through-dynamic-link), the InstantApp is not loading in response to clicking an AppLink. The symptoms are identical to the various issuetracker cases where NFC touches are not opening the InstantApp. I suspect the problem could involve the deep link workings.

I have an InstantApp in Closed testing. The release has no Stability issues and is being tested only in the US.  Installing the debug version works perfectly.

The problem is I need the click of a URL in an SMS or email to trigger an Intent to load the InstantApp and pass a query parameter value to it, i.e., the URL form is https://domain/pathPrefix/?q=parameter. AppLinks Assistant confirms the Intent with either the desired pathPrefix or pathPattern maps to the app's single Activity. Testing the Run/Debug configuration cabled to the device loads and runs the debug variant fine.

Have tried @TWL instructions to toggle or re-install Play for Instant with the same result: Triggering the SMS URL does not load the app and pass the parameter. The URL simply displays in the browser bar and its associated page displays on the screen.

Could there be a version problem in my build.gradle(app)? I am using:
'''
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-instantapps:18.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.instantapps:instantapps:1.1.0'
'''

If I complete Publishing will the desired behavior be activated? Do I have to have an Installable version? Is the lack of Full version causing the trouble?

Some SO posts indicate that a few people have found this path and URL structure does work to open the InstantApp and pass data. They have proven it is not supposed to be impossible. Can they please share what they learned?